# Python_Pandas: Among duplicate columns, choose the column with the most recent date AND THEN choose the one with maximum score

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
#Create sample df with following columns; iP,date,score,appOwner,color
df = pd.DataFrame(
                {"iP":['111.11.111.112', '111.11.111.113', '111.11.111.112', '111.11.111.112', '111.11.111.113', '111.11.111.113', '111.11.111.114', '111.11.111.114', '111.11.111.114'],
                 "date":['2016-4-3', '2016-4-2', '2016-4-2', '2016-4-5', '2016-4-3', '2016-4-2', '2016-4-3', '2016-4-3', '2016-4-1'],
                 "score":[9, 8, 8, 10, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6],
                 "appOwner":['John','Andrew','Adam','John','Andrew','Adam','Park','Doe','Jason'],
                 "color":['Green','Yellow','Unknown','Red','White','Green','Red','Yellow','Red']
                })
#Chage df['date'] dtype to datetime 
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%Y-%m-%d")

df
```

## Task note

Among duplicate IPs, choose most recent 'date' AND THEN choose 'iP' with max (higher) score.
Desired output when above is done right is below,

```
ip              date         score
111.11.111.112   2016-4-5     10
111.11.111.113   2016-4-3     6
111.11.111.114   2016-4-3     7
```

## What I've tried

```
foo = df.groupby(['iP','date'])
bar = foo['score'].agg({'maxScore':np.max})
bar
                            maxScore
iP              date    
111.11.111.112  2016-04-02  8
                2016-04-03  9
                2016-04-05  10
111.11.111.113  2016-04-02  8
                2016-04-03  6
111.11.111.114  2016-04-01  6
                2016-04-03  7
```

I'm aware that what I've tried so far isn't close to solve the task. 
By doing `least_recent_date = df['date'].min()
recent_date = df['date'].max()`, I can get the most recent, and least recent date, but that still doesn't solve the task in one piece. 
Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to identify the location of the maximum value.  This makes it easier to keep other relevant data in the same row.

So `ndf` will be a subset of `df` where every row contains a `score` that was the maximum in the `['iP', 'date']` combination.  Then among that subset, I again identify which rows contain the most recent or maximum `date` for each `iP`.  Finally, I slice the result with `['iP', 'date', 'score']`.

Keep in mind this is only one way to skin this cat.

```
ndf = df.loc[df.groupby(['iP', 'date']).score.idxmax()]
ndf.loc[ndf.groupby(['iP']).date.idxmax(), ['iP', 'date', 'score']]

               iP       date  score
3  111.11.111.112 2016-04-05     10
4  111.11.111.113 2016-04-03      6
6  111.11.111.114 2016-04-03      7
```

Comment: It looks like the order of operations came out reversed.

Comment: @gereleth I agree. I couldn't reconcile the most recent date and the numbers the OP was getting.  I felt one had to be wrong.  I chose to go with most recent data and assume expected output was incorrect.

Comment: @piRSquared Correct, I apologize for the incorrect expected output. I changed it accordingly. I think this works, and now trying to understand your solution. This will be my homework for today, and I have you updated. Thanks a lot!